# Оптимизация css кода, wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

На сайте Markway (https://markway.ru/)  есть разделы кейсов (https://markway.ru/cases/) и блогов (https://markway.ru/blog/), в которых находится множество статей . В css коде этих статей всегда повторяются определенные стили, поэтому этим разделам необходима оптимизация кода. По поводу этого возник вопрос. Можно ли привязать эти статьи к одному классу? Если нет, то есть идеи?

```css
/* СТИЛИ СТРАНИЦЫ КЕЙС: КАК УДАЛИТЬ 50 ОТЗЫВОВ ЗА ПОЛГОДА НАЧАЛО */
.case-rem-rev {
    display: block;
    max-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.case-rem-rev p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.case-rem-rev ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.case-rem-rev li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.case-rem-rev li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 11px !important;
    height: 11px !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    background: #60BEFF !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 6px !important;
}

.img-rem-rev-01 img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* 2 блок В ЧЕМ ПРОБЛЕМА ЗАКАЗЧИКА */
.strip-rem-rev-01 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.strip-rem-rev-01:before {
    content: '';
    width: 294px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #60BEFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.strip-rem-rev-01 p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.img-rem-rev-04 img {
      margin-top: 15px !important;
      margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.text-rem-rev-03 center {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.text-rem-rev-04 {
    background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.3);
    padding: 11px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* 3 блок ЧТО ТАКОЕ OTZOVIK.COM? */
.strip-rem-rev-02 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.strip-rem-rev-02:before {
    content: '';
    width: 254px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #60BEFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.strip-rem-rev-02 p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vert-rem-rev-01 ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.vert-rem-rev-01 li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 25px !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.vert-rem-rev-01 li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px !important;
    height: 76px !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    background: #60BEFF !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    top: -7px !important;
}

/* 4 блок КАК УДАЛИТЬ ОТЗЫВ С OTZOVIK.COM */
.strip-rem-rev-03 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.strip-rem-rev-03:before {
    content: '';
    width: 351px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #60BEFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.strip-rem-rev-03 p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* 5 блок РЕЗУЛЬТАТ */
.strip-rem-rev-04 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.strip-rem-rev-04:before {
    content: '';
    width: 123px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #60BEFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.strip-rem-rev-04 p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vert-rem-rev-02 ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.vert-rem-rev-02 li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 25px !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.vert-rem-rev-02 li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px !important;
    height: 55px !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    background: #60BEFF !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    top: -7px !important;
}

.btn-rem-rev-01 {
    display: flex;
}

.btn-rem-rev-01 {
    background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.28);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn-rem-rev-02 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding: 23px 0 14px 18px;
      margin: 0;
}

.btn-rem-rev-02 div:nth-child(1){
    width: 60%;
}

.btn-rem-rev-02 div:nth-child(2){
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.btn-rem-rev-02 p {
    margin: 0;
}

.btn-delete-reviews {
    width: 183px;
    height: 52px;
    background: linear-gradient(90.23deg, #FFC100 0.2%, #FFA500 99.54%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px !important;
      color: #1A2129 !important;
      font-weight: 700 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
    .strip-rem-rev-01:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .strip-rem-rev-02:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .strip-rem-rev-03:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .strip-rem-rev-04:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .vert-rem-rev-01 li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px !important;
    height: 163px !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    background: #60BEFF !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    top: -7px !important;
  }
     .vert-rem-rev-02 li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px !important;
    height: 73px !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    background: #60BEFF !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    top: -7px !important;
  }
    .btn-rem-rev-02 {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .btn-rem-rev-02 div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
  }
    .btn-rem-rev-02 {
    padding: 23px 0 15px 23px;
  }
}
/* СТИЛИ СТРАНИЦЫ КЕЙС: КАК УДАЛИТЬ 50 ОТЗЫВОВ ЗА ПОЛГОДА КОНЕЦ */
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не совсем понятно - статьи и так имеют один класс там. Или вам надо код для вордпресс для вывода статей?

Comment: `Можно ли привязать эти статьи к одному классу?` -- это как?